# Solution verification: $\lim_{x\to \infty}\Bigg(\frac{\ln(x^2+3x+4)}{\ln(x^2+2x+3)}\Bigg)^{x\ln x}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, exponential-function, limits-without-lhopital, solution-verification

> Find: $$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to
>  \infty}\left(\frac{\ln(x^2+3x+4)}{\ln(x^2+2x+3)}\right)^{x\ln x}$$

My attempt:

$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{\ln(x^2+3x+4)}{\ln(x^2+2x+3)}\right)^{x\ln x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{\ln(x^2+3x+4)-\ln(x^2+2x+3)}{\ln(x^2+2x+3)}\right)^{x\ln x}=\\\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{\ln\left(\frac{x^2+3x+4}{x^2+2x+3}\right)}{\ln(x^2+2x+3)}\right)^{x\ln x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{x+1}{x^2+2x+3}\right)}{\ln(x^2+2x+3)}\right)^{x\ln x}$

What I used:
$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}\ln\left(1+\frac{x+1}{x^2+2x+3}\right)=0\;\;\&\;\;\lim_{x\to\infty}\ln(x^2+2x+3)=+\infty$

In the end, I got an indeterminate form: $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}1^{x\ln x}=1^{\infty}$

Have I made a mistake anywhere? It seems suspicious.

added: replacement $\frac{x+1}{x^2+2x+3}$ by $\frac{1}{x}$ wasn't appealing either.

Would:$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\Big(\Big(1+\frac{1}{x}\Big)^x\Big)^{\ln x}=x=\infty$$
be wrong?

//a few days after users had provided hints and answered the question,we discussed this with our assistant and he suggested a table formula that can also be applied (essentialy the last step in methods provided in the answers I recieved).:$$\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=1\;\&\;\lim_{x\to c}g(x)=\pm\infty$$then$$\lim_{x\to c}f(x)^{g(x)}=e^{\lim_{x\to c}(f(x)-1)g(x)}//$$

Comment: So far so good, but the problem ends when you determine the limit. You can now take that chunk $\square$ and write the expression as $\left[(1+\square)^{1/\square}\right]^{\square\cdot x\ln(x)}$. Since you already saw that $\square \to0$, then $(1+\square)^{1/\square}\to e$. So, the problem reduces to compute the limit of $\square\cdot x\ln(x)$.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy, thanks, in the meantime, another dilemma appeared.

Comment: Have you tried this method: if $\lim_{x \to \infty} a^b = L$, then  $\lim_{x \to \infty} b \ln a = \ln L$ ?

Comment: @iamvegan, I've taken it into account in the very beginning, but forgot about that. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Replacing $\frac{x+1}{x^2+2x+3}$ by $\frac{1}{x}$ is not justified.

Comment: @RemigijusPankevičius According to Wolframalpha, the answer is $\sqrt{e}$. Chances are, "nice equations" will wind up being important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By your work and since $e^x$ and $\ln$ are continuous function, we obtain: $$\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\left(\frac{\ln(x^2+3x+4)}{\ln(x^2+2x+3)}\right)^{x\ln{x}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\left(1+\frac{\ln\frac{x^2+3x+4}{x^2+2x+3}}{\ln(x^2+2x+3)}\right)^{\frac{\ln(x^2+2x+3)}{\ln\frac{x^2+3x+4}{x^2+2x+3}}\cdot\frac{x\ln{x}\ln\frac{x^2+3x+4}{x^2+2x+3}}{\ln(x^2+2x+3)}}=$$
$$=e^{\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{\ln{x}\ln\left(1+\frac{x+1}{x^2+2x+3}\right)^x}{2\ln{x}+\ln\left(1+\frac{2}{x}+\frac{3}{x^2}\right)}}=e^{\frac{1}{2}\ln\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\left(1+\frac{x+1}{x^2+2x+3}\right)^{\frac{x^2+2x+3}{x+1}\cdot\frac{x(x+1)}{x^2+2x+3}}}=e^{\frac{1}{2}\ln{e}}=\sqrt{e}.$$

Comment: thank you for the explanation! May I ask, just in case, $\ln x$ in the $2^{\text{nd}}$ row cancels out, but shouldn't it be $\frac{3}{x^2}$? Constant $\frac{1}{2}$ is taken out, then we multiply $x$ by $1=\frac{x^2+2x+3}{x+1}\cdot\frac{x+1}{x^2+2x+3}$ to get $e$ again and then $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x(x+1)}{x^2+2x+3}=1$?

Comment: @VerkhovtsevaKatya I used $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{\ln{x}}{2\ln{x}+\ln\left(1+\frac{2}{x}+\frac{3}{x^2}\right)}=\frac{1}{2}.$ It was typo. I fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Use $\lim_{t\to 1}\frac{\ln(t)}{t-1}=1$ twice: first for $t=\frac{\ln(x^2+3x+4)}{\ln(x^2+2x+3)}$ and then for $t=\frac{x^2+3x+4}{x^2+2x+3}$. The rest is simplification.
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{\ln(x^2+3x+4)}{\ln(x^2+2x+3)}\right)^{x\ln x} &=
\exp\left(\lim_{x\to\infty}\ln\left(\frac{\ln(x^2+3x+4)}{\ln(x^2+2x+3)}\right)x\ln x\right) \\
&= \exp\left(\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln\frac{x^2+3x+4}{x^2+2x+3}}{\ln(x^2+2x+3)}x\ln x\right) \\
&=\exp\left(\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(x+1)x}{x^2+2x+3}\frac{\ln x}{\ln(x^2+2x+3)}\right)
\end{align} $$
We have
$$\frac{(x+1)x}{x^2+2x+3}=\frac{x^2+x}{x^2+2x+3}\to 1 $$
For the other fraction, use that $\ln(x^2+2x+3)=\ln(x^2(1+2/x+3/x^2))=2\ln x+\ln(1+2/x+3/x^2)$
$$\frac{\ln x}{\ln(x^2+2x+3)}=\frac{\ln x}{2\ln x+\ln(1+2/x+3/x^2)}=\frac{1}{2+\frac{\ln(1+2/x+3/x^2)}{\ln x}}\to \frac 12 $$
So the limit is $e^{\frac 12 \cdot 1}=\sqrt{e}$.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you see an expression of type $\{u(x) \} ^{v(x)} $ under limit it is best to take logarithms. This makes your expressions simpler and easier to type and write thereby allowing you to focus on the problem more efficiently.

Thus if $L$ is the desired limit then
\begin{align}
\log L&=\lim_{x\to\infty} (x\log x)\log\frac{\log(x^2+3x+4)}{\log(x^2+2x+3)}\notag\\
&=\lim_{x\to\infty} (x\log x) \log\left(1+\dfrac{\log\dfrac{x^2+3x+4}{x^2+2x+3}}{\log(x^2+2x+3)}\right)\notag\\
&=\lim_{x\to \infty} (x\log x) \frac{\log(1+f(x))}{f(x)}\cdot f(x)\notag\\
&=\lim_{x\to \infty} x\log x\cdot 1\cdot f(x) \notag\\
&=\lim_{x\to\infty} x\log x\cdot\dfrac{\log\dfrac{x^2+3x+4}{x^2+2x+3}} {\log(x^2+2x+3)} \notag\\
&=\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x} {2}\log\left(1+\frac{x+1}{x^2+2x+3}\right)\frac{\log x^2}{\log(x^2+2x+3)}\notag\\
&=\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x} {2}\frac{\log(1+g(x))}{g(x)}\cdot g(x) \left(1+\dfrac{\log\dfrac{x^2}{x^2+2x+3}}{\log(x^2+2x+3)}\right)\notag\\
&=\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{x} {2}\cdot 1\cdot g(x)\cdot 1 \notag\\
&=\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x(x+1)}{2(x^2+2x+3)}\notag\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\notag
\end{align}
and hence $L=\sqrt{e}$. You should be able to notice that both $$f(x)=\dfrac{\log\dfrac{x^2+3x+4}{x^2+2x+3}}{\log(x^2+2x+3)} , g(x)=\frac{x+1}{x^2+2x+3} $$ clearly tend to $0$ as $x\to \infty $.

Comment: Can you define $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ please?

Comment: @NicholasRoberts: Although they are easy to guess, I have updated my answer to include definitions for $f(x), g(x) $ for clarity.

Comment: Thanks +1 Nice answer